# Reference error can't find var cb is coming up when I click on a button for a quiz

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a reference error can't find var cb and cb is a function var for a quiz im making. next will do onclick="cb()"  but when I click next it comes up with that error Its inside of another function tho so it might be that. im using a prompt so on click of the button a prompt comes up saying the question the the user answer it right and next pops up and function is inside of the case

```
function ab() {
  var text;
  var quiza = prompt("is it gif or jif");
  switch(quiza) {
    case "gif":
      text = "Good";
      document.getElementById("a").style.display = "none"; // making the button invisible
      document.getElementById("an").style.display = "block"; // making the next button vis
      function cb() // on clicking next should do this
        {
          document.getElementById("b").style.display = "block"; // making the next q vis
          document.getElementById("an").style.display = "none"; making the next button invis
        }
      document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "1/10"; // setting the counter to 1/10
      break;
case "jif":
      text = "No";
    break;
    default:
      text = "wrong that's not gif or jif";
  }
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```
<div class="buttona" id="a"><button onclick="ab()">CLICK ME FOR 1st Q</button></div>
  <div class="next" id="an"><button onclick="cb()">Next</button></div>
```

I tried using different website for anything and it was the same I am using replit and tried with code pen but still that error .

Comment: you have a `function ab` but no `function cb` in the global scope - put that function in the global scope

Comment: yes I do `function cb() // on clicking next should do this
        {
          document.getElementById("b").style.display = "block"; // making the next q vis
          document.getElementById("an").style.display = "none"; making the next button invis
        }`

Comment: I hit enter by mistake - see edit - a function declared inside another function is not accessible in the global scopr

Comment: global scope? im new to js and stuff so can you explain?

Comment: i.e. where ab currently  is ... not inside another function

Comment: so take cb function out of ab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a function inside a function, that function will only be accessible inside the parent function, for example:

```
<script>
    function a(){
        function b(){
        }
        // 'b()' is accessible here
    }
    
    function c(){
        // 'b()' is not accessible here
    }
</script>

<!-- 'b()' is not accessible here -->
<button onclick="b()"></button>
```